# Get the text of the textView selected using Robotium

Tags: android, testing, robotium, android-testing

I am automating a product using robotium. I need to do some dat validation kind of task there.

Scenario is like:

We click on a list, select some items in the list and do some operation.

I want to put the names of the items selected into an array. Such that i can compare it later.

I used the following code:

```
for(i=0; i<=n;i++)
{
 solo.clickInList(i);
 Array1[i]=solo.getText(i).toString();
}
```

But sadly, this statement is not extracting the text of the textView selected but the id of the textView.

Please help me by giving an example of how to get the text of the TextView selected.
At a fix!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you have only listview with texts, it should work for you (I didn't test it):

```
ListView listView = solo.getView(ListView.class, 0);
String text = listView.getItemAtPosition(position));
```

Another way will be like this:

```
ArrayList<TextView> result = solo.clickInList(line);
String text = "";
for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
    text += result.get(i).getText().toString() + " ";
}
if (text.length() > 0) {
    text = text.substring(0, text.length() - 1); // remove last space
}
```